# How to check if a datetime is in %d/%m/%Y AND if its greater than a certain datetime

Tags: python, python-datetime

I'm trying to make it so that it checks if its in the format I want and if its greater than today's date. I want it to ask for input until it gets a right answer but I can't find a way to do so.

```
while True:
    try:
        x=dt.datetime.strptime(input(), '%d/%m/%Y')
        
        break
    except ValueError:
        print(1)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Maybe show an example input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`today`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.today) class method to get a `datetime` object representing today's date, and use the `>` or `<` operator to compare it to the parsed `x`:

```py
while True:
    try:
        x = dt.datetime.strptime(input(), '%d/%m/%Y')
        if x > dt.datetime.today():
            break
        else:
            print('before today')
    except ValueError:
        print('wrong format')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, date

while True:
    input_ = input('Enter a date -> ')

    try:
        dt = datetime.strptime(input_, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    except ValueError:
        dt = None
    today = date.today()

    if dt and dt > today:
        break

print('All good!')
```

->

```
Enter a date -> 12/01/2021
Enter a date -> 18/01/2021
Enter a date -> 25/01/2021
Enter a date -> 14/02/2021
All good!
```

Answer (score 0):

Customized your existing code to handle - a) Valid Date Check b) Greater than Today's Date condition.

```
import datetime as dt
while True:
    try:
        x = dt.datetime.strptime(input(), '%d/%m/%Y')
        if x > dt.datetime.now():
            print(x)
            break
        else:
            print("Please Enter a Valid Date:")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Date Format")
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution;

```
import datetime as dt

todays_date = dt.datetime.now()
todays_seconds = todays_date.timestamp()

done = False

while not done:
    user_input = input(f"Please type a date later that today's date ({todays_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}): ")

    try:
        x = dt.datetime.strptime(user_input, '%d/%m/%Y')

        if x.timestamp() <= todays_seconds:
            print("Date must be after today's date")

        else:
            done = True

    except ValueError:
        print('Input not understood, please try again')
```

Gives;

```
Please type a date later that today's date (30/01/2021): 30/01/2021
Date must be after today's date
Please type a date later that today's date (30/01/2021): 31/01/2021

Process finished with exit code 0
```